# Verification of a deep mock via mockContstructor fails

Tags: kotlin, mockk

In a test I want to verify that a model would call a client when a method of this model is called.
The class under test - the model class - is an object singleton. ([KubernetesResourceModel.kt](https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/KubernetesResourceModel.kt#L19))

```
object KubernetesResourceModel {
…
    private fun createClient(): NamespacedKubernetesClient {
        return DefaultKubernetesClient(ConfigBuilder().build())
    }
```

The actual call to the client - `DefaultKubernetesClient` - happens in an instance variable within `KubernetesResourceModel` ([Cluster.kt](https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/Cluster.kt#L56))

```
class Cluster(val client: NamespacedKubernetesClient) {
...
    private fun loadAllNameSpaces(): Sequence<Namespace> {
        return  client.namespaces().list().items.asSequence()
    }
```

In my test I stub the client and then verify that a call to the client library is executed when `KubernetesResourceModel.getAllNamespaces` is called,  ([KubernetesResourceModelTest.kt](https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/KubernetesResourceModelTest.kt#L47)):

```
    @Test
    fun `should call list namespaces on client`() {
        // given
        mockClient(emptyList())
        // when
        KubernetesResourceModel.getAllNamespaces()
        // then
        verify { anyConstructed<DefaultKubernetesClient>().namespaces().list().items }
    }
...
    private fun mockClient(namespaces: List<Namespace>) {
        // client.namespaces().list().items.asSequence()
        mockkConstructor(DefaultKubernetesClient::class)
        every { anyConstructed<DefaultKubernetesClient>().namespaces() } returns
                spyk {
                    every { list() } returns
                            spyk {
                                every { items } returns
                                        namespaces
                            }
                    every { watch(any()) } returns
                            mockk()
                }
```

The mocking works and I see `KubernetesResourceModel.getAllNamespaces()` returning the empty list that I passed along when mocking (`mockClient(emptyList())`).
Unfortunately the verification

`verify { anyConstructed<DefaultKubernetesClient>().namespaces().list().items }` ([KubernetesResourceModelTest.kt](https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/KubernetesResourceModelTest.kt#L29))

fails telling me that no call on `client.namespaces().list()` happened:

```
Verification failed: call 2 of 3: NonNamespaceOperation(child of mockkConstructor<DefaultKubernetesClient>()#1).list()) was not called
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 2 of 3: NonNamespaceOperation(child of mockkConstructor<DefaultKubernetesClient>()#1).list()) was not called
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.failIfNotPassed(VerifyingState.kt:66)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:47)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:60)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalVerify(API.kt:118)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify(MockK.kt:139)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify$default(MockK.kt:136)
    at org.jboss.tools.intellij.kubernetes.model.KubernetesResourceModelTest.should call list namespaces on client(KubernetesResourceModelTest.kt:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Does the `list()` in spyk scope actually refer to `namespaces().list()`?

Comment: And another thing. You are verifying that any constructed variable of the class should call `namespaces().list()` but you are calling the function statically (from a Companion object) I assume. Is it actually ok?

Comment: And please add the code to your question not in the comments. It is very hard to read this way. It would be nice if we have the `DefaultKubernetesClient` class implementation in the question.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari thanks for commenting. KubernetesResourceModel is a singleton object denoted as such via object KubernetesResourceModel, not a companion object. The client that I am calling namespaces() on is a property in the class Cluster which is an instance created within KubernetesResourceModel: https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/KubernetesResourceModel.kt#L34. Am I missing your point?

Comment: The client is an external dependency, DefaultKubernetesClient#namespaces is here: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/DefaultKubernetesClient.java#L175. My code is on github, it's a kubernetes plugin for intellij that I'm working on: https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/KubernetesResourceModelTest.kt#L19

Comment: Can you check that namespaces is called like: `verify { anyConstructed<DefaultKubernetesClient>().namespaces() }`

Comment: @SaeedEntezari wow, indeed, ```verify { anyConstructed<DefaultKubernetesClient>().namespaces() }``` works. thx! The actual call that I tried to mock is ```client.namespaces().list().items``` though.
How would I verify not just ```namespaces()``` but ```namespaces.list().items``` ?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari yes ```list()``` in spyk scope actually refers to ```namespaces().list()```. Sounds like I misunderstood how to use mockk?

Comment: No it's ok but I suspected something else. The namespaces function returns an object of type `NonNamespaceOperation` which has the list function I assume. Try to verify that function on this class instead and see if it works.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari yes, you're absolutely right, ```namespaces()``` returns a ```NonNamespaceOperation``` as one can see here: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/DefaultKubernetesClient.java#L175. NonNamespaceOperation extends (over a few hops) ```Listable``` (see here: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/dsl/Listable.java#L19) which offers the ```.list()``` method.
The client that I try to mock is java, does this maybe matter?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari tried your suggestion but to no avail unfortunately: I added ```mockkConstructor(NonNamespaceOperation::class)``` and a verification as you suggested: ```verify { anyConstructed<NonNamespaceOperation<*,*,*,*>>().list() }```. It fails complaining that the call didnt happen: ```Verification failed: call 1 of 1: NonNamespaceOperation(mockkConstructor<NonNamespaceOperation>()).list()) was not called```. But then, I'm very unsure about the mix of (hierarchical) mocks and constructorMock.

Comment: When I try to clone and test your code it throws `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failed to start websocket` Any idea how I can fix that to test your code?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari this pretty much shows the incomplete stubbing that is happening afaics. The websocket exception is caused by the client library that tries to connect to a undefined kubernetes client (I have one configured). With the stubbing the connection shouldn't happen: ```DefaultKubernetesClient.namespaces().watch(...)``` is what triggers the connection. In my test ```every { watch(any()) } returns mockk()``` obviously doesnt work and thus doesnt prevent this.

Comment: I started stepping through the verification code in ```mockk``` and interestingly enough I see all stubs registered (```stubRepo.allStubs```) but only stubs for kotlin classes having ```recordedCalls```. To inspect those I added a breakpoint in ```UnorderedCallVerifier#matchCall``` and manually inspected all stubs in the repo.
It thus very much looks to me as if mockk doesnt handle stubbing of java classes properly - my kubernetes client is a java library. Wrong?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari the quick hack that should fix your exception is to remove the 2 watches in the model: https://github.com/adietish/intellij-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jboss/tools/intellij/kubernetes/model/KubernetesResourceModel.kt#L40
Replace it by ```return emptyList()```.

Comment: I gave up on mockk, for some reason that I dont understand verifying the object of the java client library doesnt work. Implemented the very same using mockito-kotlin which works just fine.